# Prestashop 1.6 custom new entry field in category doesn't save

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I'm brand new to PS and I need a bit of help.
I was following: [Prestashop 1.6 - Add custom field to category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735704/prestashop-1-6-add-custom-field-to-category) and http://nemops.com/extending-prestashop-objects/#.WejLOhNSyRs to be able to add a new custom field to the admin category.

I've managed to:
- add the new field to the category UI
- add the new value to DB
- the field is populated with the value from the DB (manually entered)

but:
- I can't insert / update the value from the UI (my custom field is called: altname)

I can see that the POST is sending the value back to the 
AdminCategoriesControllerCore->postProcess()

```
Array ( [id_category] => 154 [name_1] => laci_uj_nev [name_2] => laci_uj_nev22 
    [altname_1] => Nove alternative meno [altname_2] => Nove alternative meno22
```

But it seams this value never reaches the model which should insert it into the DB.
Can someone tell me / point me to the correct direction on:
- how can I send the new value to the model which inserts the value to DB
- what is the flow of information in PS, which functions are called for update and insert?

**UPDATE**
I've identified that in AdminController.php file there is a postProcess() method which has hooks like actionAdminSaveBefore:

```
Hook::exec('actionAdmin'.ucfirst($this->action).'Before', array('controller' => $this));
```

But such hook doesn't exist, I checked all module, class, controller files, hooks table in DB, all available hooks via free modul called: hooksmanager but found nothing. Can someone point me to the correct direction to find this hook's code that I can check what it does?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

1. I've removed all and any custom code I've written.
2. Create a new file under overwrite/classes called it Category.php
3. Declare the new field's name: altname as variable (the same as in category_lang table in the DB)
4. Copy - paste the whole object model declaration from the CategoryCore class
5. Add the new field into it, see altname

```
public $altname;

public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'category',
    'primary' => 'id_category',
    'multilang' => true,
    'multilang_shop' => true,
    'fields' => array(
        'nleft' =>              array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
        'nright' =>             array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
        'level_depth' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
        'active' =>             array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'required' => true),
        'id_parent' =>          array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
        'id_shop_default' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
        'is_root_category' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
        'position' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
        'date_add' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate'),
        'date_upd' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate'),

        // Lang fields
        'name' =>               array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCatalogName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
        'altname' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName',  'size' => 128),
        'link_rewrite' =>       array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isLinkRewrite', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
        'description' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml'),
        'meta_title' =>         array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 128),
        'meta_description' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 255),
        'meta_keywords' =>      array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 255),
    ),
);
```

}